# Adding SPListItem using SPWeb.ProcessBatchData method

Tags: splistitem, spweb

I am looking for adding SPListItem using SPWeb.ProcessBatchData method. Could any one please help me on syntax for adding list item to my custom list.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use SPWeb.ProcessBatchData method then follow this tutorial,

[Inserting New Items to List using ProcessBatchData](http://www.arboundy.com/code/sharepoint/bulk-add-new-items-to-a-sharepoint-list-using-processbatchdata/)

why you must have to use "ProcessBatchData" when you can easily get SPWeb.GetList(siteURL) method to get list and add items to it.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;

namespace Test
{
   class ConsoleApp
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://localhost/sites/sitecollection"))
         {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("sitecollection/subsite"))
            {
               string listUrl = "/sites/sitecollection/subsite/Lists/Announcements";
               SPList list = web.GetList(listUrl);
               Console.WriteLine("List URL: {0}", list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl);
               SPListItem oSPListItem = list.Items.Add();
               oSPListItem["Title"] = "Hello SharePoint";
               oSPListItem.Update();
            }
         }
         Console.ReadLine();
      }
   }
}
```

taken from [MSDN GetList method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getlist)

For More examples check this out

[programmatically-add-items-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333492/sharepoint-how-can-i-programmatically-add-items-to-a-custom-list-instance)

Comment: First of thanks for taking time to answer. No doubt I can use the other approach. But in my case I am adding multiple list items inside a loop. And item.Update() inside the loop is violation of SharePoint coding rules.

Comment: I tried that before and it worked for me, however I put a link up there where he is inserting multiple items using process batch method :)